# Sony Camera Remote API beta SDK: how to deactivate auto focus on QX100?

Tags: camera, sony

Since Sony XQ100's auto-focus can be deactivated via its app-menu, is there a way to do so using the SDK? Or can "auto-focus = OFF" somehow be defined permanently for the camera, so that it can be used independently from the app?

cheers,
lara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for interest.
Sorry, this is not part of the current Camera Remote API beta.
I have also forwarded your request. If there is a way, I'll update.

API features for the Lens Style Cameras DSC-QX100 and DSC-QX10 will be expanded during the spring of 2014, to include shutter speed functionality, white balance, ISO settings and more. More information about this update will be coming later.

Best Regards,
Prem from SONY